# How to compare two columns of values between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` as below

```
a = [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["id"])

    id
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   3
5   4
6   4
7   5
8   6
```

and

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = ["apple","orange","banana","lemon","kiwi","melon"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y)), columns=["fruit_id", "fruit_name"])

    fruit_id  fruit_name
0   1         apple
1   2         orange
2   3         banana
3   4         lemon
4   5         kiwi
5   6         melon
```

I want to match the `fruit_id` from `df2` to the `id` in `df1` and generate a new column like below

```
    id  result
0   1   apple
1   1   apple
2   1   apple
3   2   orange
4   3   banana
5   4   lemon
6   4   lemon
7   5   kiwi
8   6   melon
```

Comment: A possible solution: `df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on='fruit_id').drop('id', axis=1)`.

Comment: You really don't need merge in this case, use `map` it is much more efficient. 
`df1['result'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('fruit_id')['fruit_name'])`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `pd.merge()`, which works like a SQL join

```py
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='fruit_id').drop(columns='fruit_id')
```

The merge leaves the columns from each dataframe in it initially, so you want to drop the now-unneeded fruit_id column.